# RabbitMQ on Windows. Boot failed

Tags: rabbitmq, windows-server-2008-r2

Please, help. RabbitMQ works fine on my machine, but doesn't start on other one.

RabbitMQ 3.2.4, Erlang OTPR16B03-1, Windows Server 2008 R2.
Firewall is on, but I add rule for incoming connections. In event viewer, I can see that Erlang open start listening port.

When I start service, no error is shown. Service just appears stopped after refreshing list of services.

When I run `rabbitmqctl.bat start_app`, I see this:

```
Starting node 'rabbit@WIN-T6EFNDT0P6D' ...
Error: unable to connect to node 'rabbit@WIN-T6EFNDT0P6D': nodedown
{"init terminating in do_boot",{badarg,[{io_lib,format,["- home dir: ~s~n",[[67,58,92,85,115,101,114,115,92,1040,1076,1084,1080,1085,1080,1089,1090,1088,1072,1090,1086,1088]]],[{file,"io_lib.erl"},{line,155}]},{rabbit_misc,'-format_many/1-lc$^0/1-0-',1,[]},{rabbit_misc,'-format_many/1-lc$^0/1-0-',1,[]},{rabbit_misc,format_many,1,[]},{rabbit_control_main,print_badrpc_diagnostics,1,[]},{rabbit_control_main,start,0,[]},{init,start_it,1,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1053}]},{init,start_em,1,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1034}]}]}}
```

When I run `rabbitmq-server.bat`, I get following:

```
BOOT FAILED
===========

Error description:
   {case_clause,
       {error,
           {function_clause,
               [{erl_scan,string,
                    [{error,"{file,\"C:/Users/",
                         <<"Àäìèíèñòðàòîð/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/log/rabbit@WIN-T6EFNDT0P6D.log\"}">>},
                     1,[]],
                    [{file,"erl_scan.erl"},{line,153}]},
                {application_controller,make_term,1,
                    [{file,"application_controller.erl"},{line,1605}]},
                {application_controller,conv,1,
                    [{file,"application_controller.erl"},{line,1600}]},
                {application_controller,'-get_cmd_env/1-fun-0-',2,
                    [{file,"application_controller.erl"},{line,1595}]},
                {lists,foldl,3,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1248}]},
                {application_controller,load,2,
                    [{file,"application_controller.erl"},{line,1256}]},
                {application_controller,handle_call,3,
                    [{file,"application_controller.erl"},{line,619}]},
                {gen_server,handle_msg,5,
                    [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,585}]}]}}}

Log files (may contain more information):
   undefined
   undefined

Stack trace:
   [{rabbit,ensure_application_loaded,0,[]},
    {rabbit,'-boot/0-fun-1-',0,[]},
    {rabbit,start_it,1,[]},
    {init,start_it,1,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1054}]},
    {init,start_em,1,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1034}]}]


=INFO REPORT==== 25-Apr-2014::11:15:43 ===
Error description:
   {case_clause,
       {error,
           {function_clause,
               [{erl_scan,string,
                    [{error,"{file,\"C:/Users/",
                         <<"Àäìèíèñòðàòîð/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/log/rabbit@WIN-T6EFNDT0P6D.log\"}">>},
                     1,[]],
                    [{file,"erl_scan.erl"},{line,153}]},
                {application_controller,make_term,1,
                    [{file,"application_controller.erl"},{line,1605}]},
                {application_controller,conv,1,
                    [{file,"application_controller.erl"},{line,1600}]},
                {application_controller,'-get_cmd_env/1-fun-0-',2,
                    [{file,"application_controller.erl"},{line,1595}]},
                {lists,foldl,3,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1248}]},
                {application_controller,load,2,
                    [{file,"application_controller.erl"},{line,1256}]},
                {application_controller,handle_call,3,
                    [{file,"application_controller.erl"},{line,619}]},
                {gen_server,handle_msg,5,
                    [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,585}]}]}}}

Log files (may contain more information):
   undefined
   undefined

Stack trace:
   [{rabbit,ensure_application_loaded,0,[]},
    {rabbit,'-boot/0-fun-1-',0,[]},
    {rabbit,start_it,1,[]},
    {init,start_it,1,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1054}]},
    {init,start_em,1,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1034}]}]

{"init terminating in do_boot",{rabbit,failure_during_boot,{case_clause,{error,{function_clause,[{erl_scan,string,[{error,"{file,\"C:/Users/",<<71 bytes>>},1,[]],[{file,"erl_scan.erl"},{line,153}]},{application_controller,make_term,1,[{file,"application_controller.erl"},{line,1605}]},{application_controller,conv,1,[{file,"application_controller.erl"},{line,1600}]},{application_controller,'-get_cmd_env/1-fun-0-',2,[{file,"application_controller.erl"},{line,1595}]},{lists,foldl,3,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1248}]},{application_controller,load,2,[{file,"application_controller.erl"},{line,1256}]},{application_controller,handle_call,3,[{file,"application_controller.erl"},{line,619}]},{gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,585}]}]}}}}}
```

Sorry for long stack traces.

**Update after I change RABBITMQ_BASE to `C:\RabbitMQ`**

I got this in log:

```
=CRASH REPORT==== 25-Apr-2014::21:00:05 ===
  crasher:
    initial call: application_master:init/4
    pid: <0.70.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception exit: {bad_return,
                        {{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]},
                         {'EXIT',
                             {badarg,
                                 [{io_lib,format,
                                      ["~-15s: ~s~n",
                                       ["home dir",
                                        [67,58,92,85,115,101,114,115,92,1040,
                                         1076,1084,1080,1085,1080,1089,1090,
                                         1088,1072,1090,1086,1088]]],
                                      [{file,"io_lib.erl"},{line,155}]},
                                  {rabbit_misc,format,2,[]},
                                  {rabbit,'-log_banner/0-lc$^1/1-1-',2,[]},
                                  {rabbit,'-log_banner/0-lc$^1/1-1-',2,[]},
                                  {rabbit,log_banner,0,[]},
                                  {rabbit,start,2,[]},
                                  {application_master,start_it_old,4,
                                      [{file,"application_master.erl"},
                                       {line,269}]}]}}}}
      in function  application_master:init/4 (application_master.erl, line 133)
    ancestors: [<0.69.0>]
    messages: [{'EXIT',<0.71.0>,normal}]
    links: [<0.69.0>,<0.7.0>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: true
    status: running
    heap_size: 1598
    stack_size: 27
    reductions: 241
  neighbours:
```

And there is rabbitmq-server.bat output:

```
              RabbitMQ 3.2.4. Copyright (C) 2007-2013 GoPivotal, Inc.
  ##  ##      Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/
  ##  ##
  ##########  Logs: C:/RabbitMQ/log/rabbit@WIN-T6EFNDT0P6D.log
  ######  ##        C:/RabbitMQ/log/rabbit@WIN-T6EFNDT0P6D-sasl.log
  ##########
              Starting broker...

BOOT FAILED
===========

Error description:
   {could_not_start,rabbit,badarg}

Log files (may contain more information):
   C:/RabbitMQ/log/rabbit@WIN-T6EFNDT0P6D.log
   C:/RabbitMQ/log/rabbit@WIN-T6EFNDT0P6D-sasl.log

{"init terminating in do_boot",{rabbit,failure_during_boot,{could_not_start,rabbit,badarg}}}
```

In addition, I can say that on my computer on which RabbitMQ works fine there is nothing Cyrillic. Computer on which I am trying to install and run RabbitMQ has Russian version of Windows. Unfortunately, I cannot do anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong but looks like you have Cyrillic characters in some RabbitMQ path which is probably the cause of your errors.

You have:

```
Log files (may contain more information):
   undefined
   undefined
```

Usual trace:

```
Log files (may contain more information):
   /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@host1.log
   /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@host1-sasl.log
```

Try to place all files (especially logs) to path with alphanumeric(`[A-Za-z0-9_-]`) letters and without whitespaces.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I noticed this two lines too but I had no idea how that lines should look. I'll try to do something right now.

Comment: Hmmm, do you have some firewall turned on? If you do, try to disable it temporary. If it doesn't help provide your rabbitmq config and log output too.

Comment: I tried to stop Firewall service day ago... I forgot that I works with this computer through Remote Desktop. Now, I just tried to allow and block again incoming connections... And now I am disconnected and cannot do anything. Nevertheless, yesterday, I allowed connections for Erlang executable and checked that there is no blocked connections in Event Viewer.

Comment: Hmm, have you checked that there are no other process run on the same port?

Comment: Yes. I have checked it. Moreover, Event viewer shows that erl.exe actually opens port. It seems that problem is caused by Russian version of Windows. In a few days I will try to install and and run it on other computers with Russian Windows.